# Python-Invalid syntax does not highligt error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I've been working on this code and when I test it, it says there is a syntax error but it does not highlight my error in IDLE. Any ideas?

```
import os
import sys
Start=True
while Start==True:
    Operation=input("Please select from the following operations\n"
                          "Add\n"
                          "Subtract\n"
                          "Note: Please type the option exactly as on\nscreen or you will recieve an error message.")
    if Operation==not(in("Add","Subtract")):
        print("That is not a mathmatical operation.\nPlease try again.")
        time.sleep(2)
        os.sys("cls")
    while Operation==str("Add"):
        print("You have selected Addition!")
        time.sleep(2)
        os.sys("cls")
```

Comment: Why are you doing not(in()) ?

Comment: Yep, `==not(in(...))` is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong:

```
if Operation==not(in("Add","Subtract")):
    print("That is not a mathmatical operation.\nPlease try again.")
    time.sleep(2)
    os.sys("cls")
```

Should be:

```
if Operation not in ("Add","Subtract"):
    print("That is not a mathmatical operation.\nPlease try again.")
    time.sleep(2)
    os.sys("cls")
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the line:

```
if Operation==not(in("Add","Subtract")):
```

The correct code should be:

```
if Operation not in("Add","Subtract"):
```

You also should add `import time` at the beginning of your code for the `time.sleep` to work.